# Add newlines to each line in http response

Tags: bash, http, curl, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an API (using AWS API Gateway) that obtains values from a DB and outputs them in a HTTP response.

The purpose of this is to allow users to create configuration files containing the data in the http response ie

```
curl http://api/get/data > config.conf
```

Each value in the config file needs to be on a new line ie

```
var1=x
var2=y
var3=z
```

In my API, I have set the Content-Type in my response to "text/plain", and added a "\r\n" to each line of the output.

However, when I make a request with cURL, I get:

```
var1=x\r\nvar2=y\r\nvar3=z\r\n
```

all on the same line. My shell (bash) isn't interpreting the "\r\n" as a newline.

Can anyone advise re. correct method to do this?

Should I be using "text/plain"? Do I need to tell cURL to expect these characters?

Comment: Not at all, just tested this works just fine, which means there's something wrong with your implementation. Since you're using \r\n I'm assuming you're running a windows of some description?

Comment: First thing i can thing of, is something is sanitizing your content and sending \\r\\n instead. Open a chrome, dev tools, make the request and inspect the network request, make sure in the Response tab you get exactly each value on each line. If you get escaped \r\n in the response you see them on a single line as you describe, which means I'm correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions. Turns out this was an issue with the Integration Method mapping in the AWS API Gateway, and nothing to do with the formatting of my content.

I was using:

```
$input.body
```

In the Integration Method mapping. When I changed it to:

```
$input.path('$')
```

It worked fine. I am only getting to know the AWS API Gateway, so I'm not sure why this is. From what I can see, my content was being returned as JSON content, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the case.

Comment: The difference is that $input.path('$') will output an object-notation representation of the input. $input.body should give you the raw input. Not sure where either comes into play with your backend and the response, but that's the difference between the two.

Comment: i.e. for input { "foo":"bar" } ---- $input.body -> { "foo":"bar" } ----- $input.path('$') -> {foo=bar}

Answer (score 0):

This method should work just fine. If you see "\r\n" in the output it means you've added escaped characters. How did you made "\r\n" part of the output?